# buildroot : predefs.h header error

Tags: linux, header, patch, buildroot

I'm using buildroot to build OS for Raspberry. when compiling I get this error

```
BuildRoot/bsquask/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/bits/predefs.h:20:3: error: #error "Never use <bits/predefs.h> directly; include <features.h> instead."
 # error "Never use <bits/predefs.h> directly; include <features.h> instead."
```

I searched online, [some](http://www.eglibc.org/archives/patches/msg01103.html) make a patch for this header and modify it, they say it works but not for me (I found many patches)

predefs.h

```
#ifndef _FEATURES_H
# error "Never use <bits/predefs.h> directly; include <features.h> instead."
#endif

#ifndef _PREDEFS_H
#define _PREDEFS_H

/* We do support the IEC 559 math functionality, real and complex, but only
   if a VFP coprocessor is present. If we don't have one, we fall back to
   software emulation and the functions won't work properly. So in general,
   we don't claim to support this functionality.  */
#if defined (__VFP_FP__) && !defined(__SOFTFP__)
#define __STDC_IEC_559__        1
#define __STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__    1
#endif

#endif /* predefs.h */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the file by ignoring the error (comment the line)

```
#ifndef _FEATURES_H
//# error "Never use <bits/predefs.h> directly; include <features.h> instead."
#endif
```

on my experience, it works for me fine this way